# Derivative of: $x\log_2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Can someone please help me with the derivative of this function:
$$y = x\log_2(x)$$

This is the answer:
$$1+\ln(x)\over\ln2$$

When I try to solve it I get stuck here:
$$\log_2(x) + {x\over x\ln2} =\\\log_2(x) + {1\over\ln(2)} =\\
{log(x)\over\log2} + {1\over\ln2} = \ldots$$

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: May be, use the same denominator for a fraction.

Comment: In the last line, $\log$ without subscript is to be taken as $\log_e$, i.e. $\ln$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:$$x\cdot\log_2{x}=x\cdot\dfrac{\ln{x}}{\ln{2}}$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

$$xlog_2{x}=\frac{xln(x)}{ln2}$$

Presumably you can use the product rule to differentiate this?

Remember $ln(2)$ is a constant.

Then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{ln(2)}(\frac{x}{x}+ln(x))=\frac{1+ln(x)}{ln(2)}$$ as required.